# In bootstrap v2.3.2 tooltip cuts word right in the middle

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I initialize the `tooltip` plugin as:

```
$("#id").tooltip({
   placement: 'top',
   trigger: 'hover',
   html: true,
   container: 'body'
});
```

How can this be avoided? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for your question. Because it can be useful for other members also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following:

```
word-wrap: normal
```

to your css. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found that I had added this `.tooltip-inner{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}` so it is causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have a meeting so I cannot fully cover the question. Anyway your approach is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, and setting **container: 'body'** in tooltip's options resolved my problem.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13418